# Help with debugging Qt code

Tags: c++, debugging, qt, qt-creator

Hi I got couple of questions regarding debugging Qt Code using QtCreator.

1. I primarily use mac for Qt development but also use win32. So to debug Qt code do I need to install debug library on both?
2. Say in my application I'm deleting a pointer twice. In small application I can just scan the code and figure out (at least I'll give it a try). In a big application I know I'm deleting location 003E0000 twice. Then what is the best way of determining what is being deleted and who are trying to delete it (preferably using debugger that comes with QtCreator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes you have to...
2. I suggest you to use valgrind memcheck. It works on linux and mac (I don't know whether it has windows version) and it replaces malloc and free methods and shows much information about memory handling.

valgrind --tool=memcheck

Comment: On OSX: There is "Instruments" available, witch works fine, too.

Comment: There is no valgrind for Windows. Support for OS X 10.6 (64bit binaries) was fixed recently, and works again since 3.6.0. 10.5 works since 3.5.0).

Comment: Do I need to use an external tool like this. Isn't there any trick that will let me do the same with gdb?